# python variable column into awk within python

Tags: python, variables, awk

I have the following piece of code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, sys, subprocess

yy = 22
filename = "master%d.txt" %yy
print(filename)

outlistx = "listx"

def awkfst(inname, yy, outname):
        cmd = '''awk -F "|" "$2 ~ /R1/ {print '${%d}'$4"XA"} "''' + inname + " >> " + outname %yy
        os.system(cmd)
        return

awkfst(filename, 22, outlistx)
```

The input file has the following aspect:

```
|IVS-R11032|R11032|JAN03|  3|17:00|24|HtIsKvMaNsNtNyOnSaWzYg -Ag    |NASA|BONN|22JAN18|1.0 | XA |NASA|  14 |5257|
```

And I want a file called listx, with lines like:

```
22JAN03XA
```

The original awk command line:

```
awk -F "|" '$2 ~ /R1/ { print '${y2d}'$4"XA" }' master$y2d >> listx
```

works fine.

But when running the python script I get the following error linked to my function awkfst:
"TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting"

I am really new on python and would like to move my bash script into python but don't know how to parse some information between them.

Comment: Why are you shelling out to `awk`? What can it do that you can't do easily in Python?

Comment: Don't use `os.system()`, use `subprocess.run()`. Then you don't have to worry about quoting issues.

Comment: `outname % yy` outname does not contain formatting tokens, so there is no place to insert the value of yy into that string.

Comment: Since you put the `awk` command in double quotes instead of single quotes. `$2` is being replaced by the 2nd argument to the shell, instead of referring to the field 2 of the input file.

Comment: @Barmar I had to write that way to, at least, get an output file. I tried several ways... I don't understand how to write it. I am running on windows

Comment: @JohnGordon but then don't know how to indicate the index I need

Comment: Maybe you intended to use `filename` as the `outname` argument? It has the index substituted.

Comment: @Barmar filename is the input file which in the end is: master22.txt and the output file should be listx

Comment: It sounds like you meant to have the value `list%d` for listx, so the `%d` would be replaced by 22.  But using the value `listx`, there is nowhere to put "22".

Comment: @JohnGordon ok, maybe it is because I am not sure how to parse the "22" into awk. I need that inside

Comment: The `outname % yy` string substitution is happening inside python.  It has nothing to do with awk.

Comment: @JohnGordon I think he was trying to get it into the `%d` string in the awk script, but put it in the wrong place.

Comment: You should learn to use f-strings, they're much easier.

Comment: I was able to edit python code long time ago, and I remember it was (or it seemed to be) so simple including bash code in it... And I would prefer to put awk inside because I have lots of commands like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to do it all in Python instead of using the shell to run `awk`.

```
import csv

def awkfst(inname, yy, outname):
    with open(innane) as infile, open(outname, 'w') as outfile:
        incsv = csv.reader(infile, delimiter='|')
        for row in incsv:
            if len(row) >= 4 and 'R1' in row[2]:
                outfile.write(f'{yy}{row[3]}XA\n')
```

Comment: it seems good to me, I understand de idea, but I get: "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" for the "incsv" line.

Comment: Sorry, I had an extra `:` on the line before that

Comment: it complains with sep because "is an invalid keyword argument for this function". I am trying to find how to indicate that..

Comment: Sorry, it's `delimiter`

Comment: yes! but now it does not like the list index... it says: IndexError: list index out of range. Arggg

Comment: Are there rows in the file that don't look like the example you showed? Are there blank lines?

Comment: I added a check for the row having enough fields.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256759/discussion-between-euge1780-and-barmar).

Answer (score 0):

```
'''awk -F "|" "$2 ~ /R1/ {print '${%d}'$4"XA"} "''' + inname + " >> " + outname %yy
```

This would malfunction, as due to [Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) `%` is more sticky than `+`. Consider following simple example

```
verb = "test"
ing = "%s" + "ing" % verb
```

will result in

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

as there is not place to shove verb in `"ing"`. You should use `(` and `)` to inform `python` to first concatenate then format i.e.

```
verb = "test"
ing = ("%s" + "ing") % verb
print(ing)  # testing
```